# Using many2one field in Odoo search domain

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to search based on the value of a related field using the Odoo ORM. The related field is accessed through 2 many2one relationships:

```
info = env['product.supplierinfo'].search([ \
       ('product_tmpl_id.product_variant_id.id', '=', line.product_id.id), \
       ('product_tmpl_id.product_variant_id.active', '=', True), \
       ('x_provides_stock', '=', True), \
       ('x_available_qty', '>', 0)])
```

As you can see, the first 2 tuples in the domain are searching a field through `product_tmpl_id.product_variant_id`. However, this domain does not seem to be working since I am getting many more results than I should.

If I instead add those two constraints to a filter method after the query, I get the expected results:

```
info = env['product.supplierinfo'].search([ \
       ('x_available_qty', '>', 0), \
       ('x_provides_stock', '=', True)]) \
       .filtered(lambda i: i.product_tmpl_id.product_variant_id == line.product_id and i.product_tmpl_id.product_variant_id.active)
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the first method? The documentation says that you can use a relationship traversal through a many2one field in the domain. Is this limited to only a single many2one field?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my a little similar code.

Ex.

```
    @api.model
    def _getUserId(self):
        return [('personel_ids', '=', self.env['nstdamas.employee'].search([('emp_rusers_id','=',self._uid)]).id)]


asset_ids = fields.Many2one('nstda.mst.asset','Asset', domain=_getUserId, required=True)
```